# Update typed DataSet is not committed

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset

I have code like this:

```
int selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
productds.Products[selectedRow].ItemArray = row.ItemArray;

// 1
ProductsTableAdapter padapter = new ProductsTableAdapter();

con.Open();
padapter.Update(productds.Products);
productds.Products.AcceptChanges();

adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Products ", con);
productds = new ProductDS();
adapter.Fill(productds, "products");

// 2
con.Close();
```

Here, where 1 is written I can see productds is changed so I can update it, but when I fill productds from db I can see there is no change. What should I do to commit changes to database? Database used is a `.mdb` file (MS Access).

Init method looks like this

```
con = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER = MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0; DATA SOURCE = C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\NWIND.MDB");

adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Products", con);
productds = new ProductDS();
adapter.Fill(productds, "products");
dataGridView1.DataSource = productds.Products;
con.Close();
```

Comment: first you are updating data obtained from a gridview in `padapter`. then you are selecting something else from a database into `adapter`. There seems to be no connection between these two operations. Is there any other data binding? because as it is currently written, there is just no way the changes would ever be transported to the database.

Comment: My init method looks like in the edited post. This is my first project with dbs, so this could be the reason. Could you tell me how can I update db with that structure of code I have?